# Spray scala building non blocking servlet

Tags: java, scala, servlets, spray

I've builded a scala application using spray with akka actor.

My problem is that the request are synchronized and the server can't manage many requests at once.

Is that a normal behaviour? what can I do to avoid this?

This is my boot code:

```
object Boot extends App with Configuration {

  // create an actor system for application
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-service")
//context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[TestActor]), "router")
  // create and start property service actor
  val RESTService = system.actorOf(Props[RESTServiceActor], "my-endpoint")

  // start HTTP server with property service actor as a handler
  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(RESTService, serviceHost, servicePort)
}
```

actor code:

```
class RESTServiceActor extends Actor 
                            with RESTService  {
  implicit def actorRefFactory = context

  def receive = runRoute(rest)
}



trait RESTService extends HttpService  with SLF4JLogging{
  val myDAO = new MyDAO



  val AccessControlAllowAll = HttpHeaders.RawHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
  )
  val AccessControlAllowHeadersAll = HttpHeaders.RawHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  )
  val rest =  respondWithHeaders(AccessControlAllowAll, AccessControlAllowHeadersAll) { 
    respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`){
      options {
            complete {
              ""
            }
          } ~
      path("some"/"path"){
         get {
            parameter('parameter){ (parameter) => 
              ctx: RequestContext =>
                    handleRequest(ctx) {
                      myDAO.getResult(parmeter)
                    }
            }
          }
        } 
    }
  }

    /**
   * Handles an incoming request and create valid response for it.
   *
   * @param ctx         request context
   * @param successCode HTTP Status code for success
   * @param action      action to perform
   */
  protected def handleRequest(ctx: RequestContext, successCode: StatusCode = StatusCodes.OK)(action: => Either[Failure, _]) {
    action match {
      case Right(result: Object) =>
        println(result)
        ctx.complete(successCode,result.toString())
      case Left(error: Failure) =>
      case _ =>
        ctx.complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
    }
  }
}
```

I saw that:

> Akka Mist provides an excellent basis for building RESTful web
>   services in Scala since it combines good scalability (enabled by its
>   asynchronous, non-blocking nature) with general lightweight-ness

Is that what I'm missing? is spray using it as default or I need to add it, and how?

I'm a bit confuse about it. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting from scratch, I suggest using Akka HTTP, documented at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M4/scala/http/. It is a port of Spray, but using Akka Streams, which will be important moving forward.

As far as making your code completely asynchronous, the key pattern is to return a `Future` to your result, not the result data itself. In other words, `RESTServiceActor` should be return a `Future` that returns the data, not the actual data. This will allow Spray/Akka HTTP accept additional connections and the asynchronous completion of the service actor will return the results when they are finished.

Comment: Can you show me how to return a `Future` according my service actor code(included in question)?

Comment: In the case of this code, the ```myDAO.getResult(parmeter)``` is what is doing the actual work. Assuming you are using something like spray-json to serialize the result, you will want to call ```ctx.complete()``` with ```Future { myDAO.getResult(parmeter) }```. You'll need to handle errors, for instance with the patterns shown in http://www.superloopy.io/articles/2013/spray-routing-error-handling.html.

Comment: Akka HTTP is not marked as production ready, so that might not be the best option.

Comment: @Przemek: It will be production ready by the time any app is finished with it. The APIs are final, that's what's important.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending result to the complete method:

```
ctx.complete(successCode,result.toString())
```

I used the future method:

```
import concurrent.Future
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

ctx.complete(successCode,Future(Option(result.toString())))
```

Comment: Surprised at the "unaccept", most people add this kind of content as an **UPDATE** section on their OP when a contributor leads them there.